# Libre Office Impress media insert for complete presentation, not only slides

Tags: sound, libreoffice

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS. When I was making up a PowerPoint presentation in Impress, I couldn't figure out how to make a music selection play continously throughout the slide show.

It starts on the first slide but then stops and starts over again when the second slide presents and on down the line. I want to make this sound playing all the way continously.  The "Help" file didn't make it clear how to do that.

I want to embed sound file into the presentation, so it can be put on a CD, then be used in another Linux computer also later.

Comment: Hi, Gary. What Impress are you using? Apache OpenOffice, LibreOffice... what version? 3, 4, 5? I guess it's LibreOffice 5.1.6, ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Slide Transition pane to set up Impress so that a sound or a song is played throughout the presentation. To do that:

1. Select the slide where you want the sound to start and go to the
   Slide transition pane.
2. In the 'Modify transition' section, select the entry 'Other sound' from the Sound drop-down menu.
3. Select the 'Loop until next sound' checkbox if you want the sound to restart once it is finished.

**Caution**:

Do NOT click the 'Apply to all' button, otherwise your selected sound will restart at every slide.

If you just do slide transitions, nothing happens. You need to go to the 'View' and activate the sidebar, then it works.

Comment: TNX--I got it working for now--I was clicking the "Apply to all" and that was what was messing me up supposedly.

Comment: Am using the Libre office version 5.1.6.2

Comment: Gary, if the answer helped you, please mark it as correct. This is a huge benefit to others searching for a solution.